# IdentityServer4: Invalidate or sign out of the cookie identity as part of Authorization cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a website that is authenticated by an external instance of IS4.

I am adding the ability to sign in via a authentication code, this code is passed in via an ACR value.

It works, but for robustness I am adding some validation checks for when there is an existing IS4 identity cookie stored on the IS4 domain, from say a previous sign in. In this case, I need to invalidate / sign out of the IS4 identity cookie when certain conditions are met.

I followed the advice given in the answer to this question:

[Add checks in IdentityServer login before redirecting to client app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161827/add-checks-in-identityserver-login-before-redirecting-to-client-app)

However, IS4 just presents the user with a validation error.

Is there any way to get IS4 to invalidate the identity cookie and present the user with the login screen like it would do if there wasn't an existing identity cookie?

I considered looking for a special error code when the Error action executes, sign out and redirect back to the app so it can repeat the authentication cycle, however the `RedirectUrl` property on the Error object is a bit useless as it has the client's oidc sign-in url and if I redirect to that, the app will be expecting a correct response to that endpoint to complete the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I just blogged about how to invalidate issued cookies in ASP.NET Core at

[Improving ASP.NET Core Security By Putting Your Cookies On A Diet](https://nestenius.se/2024/01/22/improving-asp-net-core-security-by-putting-your-cookies-on-a-diet/)

Issued cookies are by default not "invalidated" in ASP.NET Core when you signout, and by using a Session Store for the issued cookies (by AddCookie) then you can invalidate any session cookie.

Perhaps you can apply the same technique to IdentityServer.

Comment: That's an amazing blog post which happens to address another issue which is in our backlog - and I can see if we did the same for the identity inside IS4 then we could more easily invalidate the identity arbitrarily. 

I'll leave this question marked as unanswered for a bit longer in case anyone knows of a way to get IS4 to do what I want, but this is a promising solution.

Comment: Great! Glad it matches your issues :-) Feel free to accept my answer when you feel like :-) I do blog about common issues I find here on Stack Overflow.